# Loading JS File

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a website structure

```
  /
  /users
  /users/wishes
```

I am using ExpressJS, Jade, and vanilla JS for front-end with 2 separate js files using `window.onload` function to set up my onclicks. I am expecting that my clients first open `/` and after this they proceed to the other pages. I have 3 views for each of the pages. Since the website is pretty small I decided not to do overkill by using a JS Framework.

Now I want to minimize my JS files inside a single one, as usual, and load everything in the root. However, it does not seem to work. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: since your website is small, you can manually create minified version of your JS file by using online tools and placing it in one file

Comment: Minifying is not a problem. Problem is that I have 1 file for `/users` and a different file for `/users/wishes`. They both use the `window.onload` function.

Comment: If you want to put both these inside one js, then you will want to create a function to init page1, & page2.. just expose say 2 functions called   `initPage1` & `initPage2` etc, and place you onload inside the functions..  And then on each page call the required `initPage`.  You could even create one simple function with a page reference as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks I will try that!

Comment: I found this [link](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm) which explains it pretty well. Thanks for your help @Keith

Comment: Are you using Gulp for workflow? If yes, there are packages that can do this step automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for event instead of replacing window.onload function.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('here you go !');
})
```

But take note, that if listener will be added after event fires, it wont execute.